# .Findnext not respecting the range set

Tags: excel, vba, find

In my code I use two instances of `.Find`, combined with a `.FindNext`. Which is notoriously prone to errors, unfortunately I'm no exception. However this is the best I could come up with. Code below, where I stripped most irrelevant stuff.

The problem is that there are duplicate values, which I want to keep both, so I decided to use `.Findnext` if there is a duplicate, using:

```
If newqst = refqst Then
    Set newqstadrs = Findrange.FindNext(after:=lstqstadrs)
Else
```

The problem here is that `.FindNext` doesn't respect that it should continue on the `Findrange.Find`, but continues on the `FindRangeTwo.Find` used here:

```
newrowtwo = FindRangeTwo.Find(rCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).row
```

**Full Code:**

```
For o = 72 To lastrow 

    Dim refqst As String
    refqst = wss.Cells(o, 1).Value
    If Not refqst = "" Then
        If InStr(refqst, ".") > 0 Then
            Dim Findrange As Range
            Dim newqst As String
            Dim newqstadrs As Range
            Dim lstqstadrs As Range

            If newqst = refqst Then
                Set newqstadrs = Findrange.FindNext(after:=lstqstadrs)
            Else

                Select Case Left(refqst, 1)
                    Case 1
                        Set Findrange = wsa.Range(wsa.Cells(4, gewaskolom), wsa.Cells(11, gewaskolom))
                    'some more cases here
                End Select
                Set newqstadrs = Findrange.Find(refqst, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            End If

            If newqstadrs Is Nothing Then
            Else
                newqst = newqstadrs.Value
                Dim newrow As Long
                newrow = Findrange.Find(refqst, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).row
                Dim lstqst As String

                If Not wsa.Cells(newrow, 1) = "" Then
                    'do some stuff         
                    lstqst = refqst
                    Set lstqstadrs = newqstadrs

                ElseIf Not wsa.Cells(newrow, 2) = "" Then

                    Dim FindRangeTwo As Range
                    Set FindRangeTwo = wsa.Range(wsa.Cells(newrow, gewaskolom), wsa.Cells(wsa.Range("B" & newrow).End(xlDown).row, gewaskolom))
                    Dim SearchRange As Range
                    Set SearchRange = wss.Range(wss.Cells(o + 1, 1), wss.Cells(wss.Range("B" & o).End(xlDown).row, 1))
                    Dim rCell As Range
                    For Each rCell In SearchRange
                        Dim newrowtwo As Long
                        newrowtwo = FindRangeTwo.Find(rCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).row
                        'do some more stuff
                    Next rCell
                    lstqst = refqst
                    Set lstqstadrs = newqstadrs
                End If
            End If            

        End If
    End If
Next o
```

Comment: You can only have one Find/FindNext pair. The second overrides the first. You need an alternate method for FindRangeTwo. Given that FindRangeTwo is a single column (gewaskolom), application.match should do nicely.

Comment: I was affraid of that. Back to the drawingboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one Find/FindNext pair. The second overrides the first. You need an alternate method for FindRangeTwo. Given that FindRangeTwo is a single column (gewaskolom) and you are looking for the row, application.match should do nicely.

Something like this,

```
dim newrowtwo as variant   '<~~ should be variant type for IsError to catch

...
newrowtwo = application.match(rCell.Value, FindRangeTwo, 0)
if not iserror(newrowtwo) then
    ...
end if
...
```

Note that application.match is returning the position within FindRangeTwo, not the row on the worksheet. The actual row on the worksheet would be (newrowtwo + newrow - 1).

Comment: The iserror is to catch the event in which a match can't be found?

Comment: That's correct. Application.Match thrown to a variant will return a row number (position within the match range) if found or an error that can be caught with IsError if not. Has to be a variant and does not work with worksheetfunction.match.

Comment: Thanks, just to be sure I put the `newrowtwo = newrowtwo + newrow -1` within the `if not iserror` and it works like a charm.